# jpegcam in jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use jpegCam wiht jquery. I tried to use jquery modal dialog to open jpegcam window but there is a problem with `document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );` .

here is example of my code:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>scan</legend>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <script language=\"JavaScript\">
        webcam.set_api_url( 'core/img_upload/_php_upload_doc_img.php' );
        webcam.set_quality( 99 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
        webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
    </script>
    <div id='web'>
    <script language=\"JavaScript\">

    document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );

    </script>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>

    <script language=\"JavaScript\">
        webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', 'my_completion_handler' );

        function take_snapshot() {
            // take snapshot and upload to server
            document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = '<p>uploading...</p>';
            webcam.snap();
        }

        function my_completion_handler(msg) {
            // extract URL out of PHP output
            if (msg.match(/(https\:\/\/\S+)/)) {
                var image_url = RegExp.$1;
                // show JPEG image in page
                document.getElementById('upload_results').innerHTML = 
                    '<img src=\"' + image_url + '\">';

                // reset camera for another shot
                webcam.reset();
            }
            else alert(\"PHP Error: \" + msg);
        }
    </script>



 <div id=\"upload_results\" ></div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<div class='div_button'>
<table class='pok'>
<tr>
 <form>
        <input type='button' value=\"skenuj\" onClick=\"take_snapshot()\" class='web' />
        <input type='button' value=\"konfigurace\" onClick=\"webcam.configure()\" class='web' />

    </form>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</fieldset> 


     jquery functions

    $('#sc_id').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 800,
                    modal:true,

                });

    $('#scan_id').click(function(){
                 $('#sc_id').dialog('open');
                return false;
          });
```

jpegcam source: webcam.js and webcam.swf are without changes..... 
thanks for any reply.......:)

Answer (score 2):

you have to put this on top of your sc

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jpegcam/htdocs/webcam.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jpegcam/htdocs/._webcam.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```